# How to use subdivide on this shape that i cant name

Tags: modeling

I'm kinda new to blender and i'm trying to model ww2 gun m1928 thompson.
Ive modeled a handguard at front of the gun:

[image: thompson hanrdguard model]

When i try to apply subdivide modifier, it makes this weird shape:

[image: handguard glitch]

Here is also edit mode of the object:

[image: edit mode hanguard]

Ive used boolean value to create this shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As R-800 says, if you want to give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, you should avoid ngons, because the *Subdivision Surface* will divide these ngons and create overlapping faces. If you want to use a *Subdivision Surface*, you can create a much lighter topology, like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose edges you want to keep sharp then go Edge>mark crease (Shift+E) and drag up for maximum value

Comment: Sharpening the edges won't solve the problem. The problem is ngons. The Subdivision Surface modifier doesn't like them. It's always going to go nuts if you have them. You want quad-based topology if you're going to use the Subdivision Surface modifier. That said, the OP doesn't actually need a Subdivision Surface modifier in the first place because the project can be achieved entirely with hard surface modeling techniques.

Comment: Yeah sorry totally forgot that. Deleting the Ngon-faces and then Faces>fill faces (Alt+F) works for me normally + faces> tris to quads. Or you can try using knife tool (K) to make it quads

Comment: Thank you! I had to look up the ngon definition, and from that ive assumed that you meant those faces that are around that custom shape in middle, ive deleted them and made these ones:
https://imgur.com/a/EiZhvnO
Is this right aproach or can i do it better?

Comment: That's fine, but what I'm trying to say is that for the kind of model you are making (hard surface - yet another term to look up), avoiding ngons isn't all that important.